автосоздание папок а также безпрерывная запись в файл на bash
    #!/bin/bash

MAX_FILESIZE=100024  # 1024 байта = 1 КБ
NUMBER_OF_FILES=5

# Это функция, которая делает «типа, записал»
tipa_write() {
    touch $1
    while [ "$(wc -c < $1 )" -lt $MAX_FILESIZE ]; do
        echo "текст в файле" >> $1
        # тут логика твоего типазаписала
    done
}

# Это цикл, который делает «записал, сжал, удалил для $NUMBER_OF_FILES файлов
# с именами по номерам (в примере — от 1 до 100)
for filenum in $(seq $NUMBER_OF_FILES); do
    # пишем
    tipa_write "$HOME/ziper/$dirname/filanems$filenum"
    # жмём
    bzip2 "$HOME/ziper/$dirname/filanems$filenum"
    # удаляем непожатое
    rm -f "$HOME/ziper/$dirname/filanems$filenum"
# И переходим к следующему файлу
done

при обрыве записи создается идентичный файл на запись, мне нужно что бы запись была не прерывная в одном и том же файле до обозначенного предела даже если ее прервать а также авто создание папки для этих файлов.
если в вкратце, что нужно, авто создание папки, авто создание файлов в ней, авто сжатие каждого файла, не прерывная запись в файл.
что уже реализовано, авто создание файлов, авто сжатие.
помогите дописать код.

Выглядит как logrotate

logrotate само собой)
